# Execute code after all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to do some interface fixes after all images are loaded (need the heights of the elements that hold images and use them to change the heights of other elements) I attach load event to all images but my load function is executed only once. I've try to use only jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var $img = $('img');
    var length = $img.length;
    var count = 0;

    function load() {
       console.log(++count + ' == ' + length);
       if (count == length) {
          // all images loaded
       }
    }
    $img.load(load).error(load);
});
```

I also try to use onload and onerror events:

```
$img.each(function() {
    this.onload = load;
    this.onerror = load;
});
```

but when page is loaded I've got just one log:

```
1 == 33
```

(I'm testing in Chromium on Xubuntu with Dev Tools and cache disabled)

What I've doing wrong here? How to execute code after all images are loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you should be handling on the `window`'s `load` event:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
// Glorious code!!
}
```

From the docs: "Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics."

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: no he shouldn't because some older browser could not fired onload event on image already loaded. But then if OP not use specific onload event for each image, this will let him calculate height for each image, so this is a possible fix

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in that yes, you are correct in that this should replace the individual handlers in favour of a broader approach.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the function when the page has finished loading

```
$(window).load
```

That way all elements are in place and ready to be 'measured'

Comment: $(window).load(function(){})